# Failed IOS Build React Native

Tags: ios, react-native, build, terminal, ios-simulator

I downloaded a branch from my github project and when I run the simulator, it runs but the app displays this error.

I have already tried removing the build folder and re running it and I have done npm install when the error displays and running "react-native run-ios". I don't know what to do.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Open additional terminal in the same folder. Run this command.

> react-native start --reset-cache

Once the package manager is ready, go back to your first terminal and run your app again.

> react-native run-ios

Comment: the package manager isn't running when I run 'react-native run-ios'. Thats the probelm